# TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__' in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on a project in Python. I am a beginner and I am getting this error when I am running the program.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python/1616/checkProfile.py", line 104, in <module>
    p.getResults()
  File "E:\Python\1616\Profile.py", line 67, in getResults
    for i in range(2): self._s[1]  += e.getS[1]
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'


Error in Line 67
```

http://pastebin.com/HXvppfmU

Comment: Please upload your code as well

Comment: That means you're trying to use `[]` on a float, which doesn't make any sense. I'm going to guess `self._s` is a float? Impossible to say for sure though without more code for context.

Comment: You are trying to call a get method on a float data type, which doesn't work because the float data type has no get method.

Comment: Seems like a lot of new posters these days need to try their luck at begging volunteers for special/urgent treatment, get heavily downvoted as could have easily been predicted, then learn from the experience...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to check what are the methods allowed for datatypes,

```
dir(datatype)
# As for float, try dir(float)
#This will suggest you that there is no method called __getitem__ for float.
# You might be trying to get some data or you are using []/()/{} which is not correct.
```

Try to post ur code.